# compare characters in two columns for each row - find things that don't match

Tags: r

I can think of several convoluted ways to do this, but what is the most efficient?  My data set could have more than 10,000 rows.

Sample data:

```
example = structure(list(set = structure(c(2L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 
6L, 11L, 12L), .Names = c("87", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", 
"563", "564", "565", "95"), .Label = c("A/C", "A/G", "A/T", "C/A", 
"C/G", "C/T", "G/A", "G/C", "G/T", "T/A", "T/C", "T/G"), class = "factor"), 
    line1 = c("G", "G", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "T", "C", "G"
    ), line2 = c("A", "A", "G", "T", "T", "G", "G", "C", "T", 
    "A")), .Names = c("set", "line1", "line2"), row.names = c(5L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

looks like:

```
> example
   set line1 line2
5  A/G     G     A
7  A/G     G     A
8  G/A     A     G
9  T/C     C     T
10 T/C     C     T
11 A/G     A     G
13 A/G     A     G
14 C/T     T     C
15 T/C     C     T
16 T/G     G     A
```

I want to find rows where the characters in line1 and line2 are not in the "set" column.  Ideal output would be something like this:

```
   set line1 line2 check
5  A/G     G     A  TRUE
7  A/G     G     A  TRUE
8  G/A     A     G  TRUE
9  T/C     C     T  TRUE
10 T/C     C     T  TRUE
11 A/G     A     G  TRUE
13 A/G     A     G  TRUE
14 C/T     T     C  TRUE
15 T/C     C     T  TRUE
16 T/G     G     A FALSE
```

I imagine I need to parse each set into something.. but I'm a little stuck.  Maybe this:

```
strsplit(as.character(example$set), "/")
```

Then use setdiff ?

Comment: what would be the check status for T/C | T | C ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid character comparisons and use more numerical methods with a strategy like this

```
#create factors, set up loop up table
g <- setNames(2^((1:4)-1), c("A","C","G","T"))
gg <- setNames(
    c(outer(as.numeric(g), as.numeric(g), bitwOr)),
    outer(names(g), names(g), paste, sep="/")
)
```

This recodes A,C,G,T as 1, 2, 4, 8. We then bitwise "or" the values together for the genotypes. This basically turns the values into a 4 flags that track which alleles are present in which genotype.

```
example$check <- apply(mapply(bitwAnd, 
    lapply(example[,2:3], function(x) g[x]), 
    MoreArgs=list(gg[as.character(example$set)])), 1, all)
```

We use the inner `lapply()` to convert the ACTG's in example, to the numerical equivalents. Then we use the mapply to bitwise-and each of the single values with the `set` column to make sure that *each* allele is present in the genotype. Finally, we do an overall `apply` to verify that *both* alleles are in the genotype. This gives us

```
   set line1 line2 check
5  A/G     G     A  TRUE
7  A/G     G     A  TRUE
8  G/A     A     G  TRUE
9  T/C     C     T  TRUE
10 T/C     C     T  TRUE
11 A/G     A     G  TRUE
13 A/G     A     G  TRUE
14 C/T     T     C  TRUE
15 T/C     C     T  TRUE
16 T/G     G     A FALSE
```

Comment: This is amazing. First time i see Bitewise Logical Op being used. I'd like to see the code commented because I can't reach it! Thanks!

Comment: @PauloCardoso I tried to add some more description, but it's probably not the best way to approach the problem. Though I wonder if it may be faster than string based comparisons.

Comment: This is faster than @thelatemail setdiff method - though that method is easier to interpret :)

`user  system elapsed
0.030   0.008   0.035`

vs

   user  system elapsed 
  0.114   0.009   0.122 

for my full dataset..

Answer (score 2):

This should be extendable to including any number of line1/2/n variables:

```
with(example, mapply(
  function(x,...) length(setdiff(x,c(...))) == 0, 
  strsplit(as.character(set),"/"), 
  line1,
  line2
))

# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to get to.  Nice one

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
L <- 1:dim(example)[1]
in1 <- sapply(L, function(i) length(grep(example$line1[i], example$set[i])))
in2 <- sapply(L, function(i) length(grep(example$line2[i], example$set[i])))
example$check <- in1 & in2
```

Comment: indeed it works, not quite as fast as the other approach